# Reset Settings Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, settings

Does anyone know how I could reset all of the settings in my app? Imagine I have some checkboxes and list preferences. How could I reset everything to how it was just after the app was installed - the checkbox preferences are checked/unchecked, the list preferences reset to the default value)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = Context.getSharedPreferences("FileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Just call `editor.clear();` to reset it.

Comment: Thanks, I did that already (though with `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());`). Though I just figured out that I need to restart the whole application in order checkbox/list preferences are set to the default values.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `editor.clear();`
It will reset the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have default values set for each pref in the XML file. E.g.:

```
android:defaultValue="3600000"/>
```

Then you can do this in the code:

```
// Log.d(TAG, "Setting default preference values.");
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.prefs, false);
```